# What function $f(x,t)$ could be used to describe the purple curve in this animation

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[Here is the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlnLD.gif)

I stumbled across this by accident and have become intrigued by it. The key point is that the purple curve is always tangential to the two other curves (`3/2 * cos(x) + 3` and `-3/2 * cos(x) - 3`) at two points separated by an x distance of 2. If you would like to change the two starting curves to avoid the awkward y-axis intervals and the non-pi multiples on the x-axis then that is fine.

All I can do is guess work and trial and error since I've never seen a method for solving problems like these so hopefully someone has a solution to give an exact answer in a bit more contrived way.

Comment: The upper limiting curve is more pointed nearer x-axis than outside. Doubt it is a displaced cosine curve as stated.

Comment: @Narasimham Yeah, it looks like the two curves are the envelope of the blue curve family.

Comment: That is so,but the given curves are not displaced cosine curves.

Comment: My apologies. That was an assumption I probably shouldn't have made. Are you saying the blue curve is sinusoidal then and the other two are the ones of interest?

Comment: Yes, that is what. Your question is about the envelope of the pulsating/moving  dynamic cosine curve.Perhaps you like to alter the question that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

If the envelope is known, one way is by taking $y$ in form

$$ y = f(t) \sin ( x +t) \tag {1} $$

To obtain singular solution we can use $C-$ discriminant method starting by partially differentiating above w.r.t.$t$

$$  f'(t) \sin ( x +t) +f(t) \cos ( x +t)  =0 \tag {2} $$

and eliminating $t$ between (1,2), equate the eliminant to given envelope/singular solution to find an $f$. As the envelope is not fully given, some connecting guessing  is needed.

EDIT1:

If you are comfortable with *Mathematica* an animation of one solution set (from anderstood,corey979 yesterday to my query at the SE site) results from:

```
Clear[a]; f[x_, a_] = Cos[x + a] + Cos[x]^2;
plots = Table[
   Plot[f[x, a], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}], {a, -4, 4, .5}];
frames = FoldList[Show, First@plots, Rest@plots];
ListAnimate[frames, AnimationRate -> 4]
```

[Animation_of_Trig_function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130944/animated-plot-required-to-leave-behind-trace)

[image: Envelope_SineWave]

However needs more guessing/playing with $ f(x,a). $

Comment: The envelope being the two curves on the outside? If so could we just assume they are cos(x) + 2, cos(x) - 2 respectively just so I can see an example of the method for finding f(t)? I gave this a go but don't really follow what you are suggesting doing for the last bit.

Comment: It is not done yet. It may take  more time. Do you have or tried any animation software?

Comment: I haven't, no. I've never really approached problems in any other way than using convensuonal algebraic methods. I'm reading up on some lessons and articles about envelope curves. The field seems a lot more complex than I first imagined but I'll see what I can grasp from it

Answer (score 1):

I have found a family of curves $C_a$ (where $a$ is a parameter) with equations:

$$\tag{1}y=f_a(x)=(3+(3/2)\sin(a))\sin(x-a)$$

As $a$ varies, the snake-like movement of these curves is like on the video.

> Moreover the locus of maximum (resp. minimal) points of curves $f_a$ is exactly curve $y=3/2\cos(x)+3$ (resp. $y=-3/2\cos(x)+3$).

BUT the (double) envelope of the family is constituted by curves that are close to curves $y=\pm3/2\cos(x)+3$, but cannot be pure sinusoids, as has been remarked by @Narasimham (too spiky).

Remark: I have attempted to obtain an implicit or parametric expression of the envelope by the classical technique (elimination of parameter $a$ between expression (1) and its derivative with respect to $a$). But I have not obtained significant results.